# Regex to get positive number

Tags: android, regex

I have a string that contains a number in between and I want to get all the numbers from that string for that I have this regex ( \d+ ) but it's not serving the purpose.

[image]

I also want to include those that are mentioned in red square, what changed do I need to make in the regex.

**Edit:** Relevant code

```
String regex = "( \\d+ )";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(textView.getText());

        while (m.find()) {
            String number = m.group().replace(" ", "");
            WAAFILogger.d("Number-regex", ":"+number+":");
            int startIndex = messageText.indexOf(number);
            int endIndex = startIndex + number.length() - 1;

            builder.setSpan(message.getSpannableListenerForNumber(number),
                    startIndex,
                    endIndex + 1,
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        }
```

Comment: Do you want to say you want to avoid matching dates? Are you replacing, extracting, removing matches? Please provide your regex relevant code to see where you are heading.

Comment: extracting. Also added the code, please check,

Comment: I suggest [this approach](https://ideone.com/kjthrH), with `String regex = "\\b\\d{1,2}\\s+\\w+\\s+\\d{2}(?:\\d{2})?\\b|(?<!\\S)(\\d+)(?!\\S)";`. Match the dates and only extract other numbers enclosed with whitespaces.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not picking anything.  Tried on regex101

Comment: [Works wonders](https://regex101.com/r/wVzIrE/1) at regex101. You need the green ones.

Comment: If you use the `regex` declaration I shared above, you need to check `if (m.group(1) != null)` and only then proceed with the match handling in your code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please check this https://regex101.com/r/yTvJGy/1

Comment: You are testing it wrong, you must test a *string* pattern, not a *string literal*. See [the right demo](https://regex101.com/r/yTvJGy/2). Again, see **[the JAVA code demo](https://ideone.com/kjthrH)**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried the sample but from this sample "18 mai 2007 and 123354 and +1234" it only picked 123345. I want all these numbers to be picked.

Comment: By "all" you mean `18`, `2007`, `123354` and `1234`?

Comment: yes and also +1234

Comment: Ok, so you need `String regex="(?<!\\S)\\+?\\d+(?!\\S)"`, see [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yTvJGy/3)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's working well, One thing though what if I want to pick +33444 from "abc+33444" as well. Meaning, if number prefix with the plus, it doesn't matter if it has space on left or right. pick it always.

Comment: Oh, you need `\+?\b\d+(?!\S)`, `String regex="\\+?\\b\\d+(?!\\S)";`. Or `\+?(?<!\d)\d+(?!\d)`, `String regex="\\+?(?<!\\d)\\d+(?!\\d)";`. Please test and let know which one best fits your scenario.

Comment: Or, `\+?(?<!\d|\d\.)\d+(?!\.?\d)`? See https://regex101.com/r/zhteZ5/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, it's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use either of the two:

```
\+?\b\d+(?!\S)
\+?(?<!\d|\d\.)\d+(?!\.?\d)
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/zhteZ5/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/zhteZ5/1). Details:

- `\+?` - an optional `+` sign
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!\d|\d\.)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit or digit + `.` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is no non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?!\.?\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is an optional `.` and a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: One small thing though if a number starts with + it doesn't matter if it has spaces on left or right, pick it always. But it also picking the number that has not plus. Please check. https://regex101.com/r/ueHJPm/1

Comment: @user2934930 Correct, you get `+923155104292` and `92928392992` - what do you expect?

Comment: Try `\+\d+|\b(?<!\d\.)\d+\b(?!\.\d)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ueHJPm/4)

Comment: Thanks, that better matches my requirement.